# Ring with multiplicative one equals to additive zero implies that the ring can only have one element

Tags: ring-theory

I've heard a statement in an math outreach lecture that if we have a ring where "unity element by addition e equals to multiplicative zero than this ring has exactly one element". I've tried to derive it from the axioms of the ring but was unsuccessful. How to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R$ be a ring with $1=0$. Then for $r\in R$ we have $r=r1=r0=0$ so $R=\{0\}$.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, because $0=0+0$, for any $r \in R, r \cdot 0=r \cdot (0+0)=r \cdot 0+r \cdot 0,$ and adding $-(r \cdot 0)$ to both sides yields $0=r \cdot 0$.

Comment: The main answer was not obvious, but the comment is. The accepted answer goes to this comment...

Comment: @sixtytrees You can always ask for clarifications in the comments. Moreover, if you know what a ring is, you should also be able to prove this yourself.